# Show that $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a Splitting Field for Polynomial $x^q-x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I have been given a homework problem which asks me to assume that $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a field of order $q$, and to show that $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a splitting field for the polynomial $x^{q}-x\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, using Lagrange's theorem on the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Can you please help me to find a suitable approach to this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I just want to make a small note: $\Bbb F_{q}$ is not only *a* field of order $q$, it's *the* field of order $q$.  For each prime $p$ and $n \in \Bbb N$, there exists a *unique* field of order $p^{n}$, and every finite field is of order $p^{n}$ for some prime $p$ and natural number $n$.  So we assume $\Bbb F_{q}$ is *the* field of order $q$ (since there is only one).

Comment: That's what the exercise shows; splitting fields are unique (up to iso).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^q - x$.    To show that $f$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_q$, we wish to demonstrate the existence of $q$ roots of $f$ inside of this field, perhaps counting multiplicity.  Now if $x$ is a root of $f$, then notice it must satisfy $x^q = x$.  Trivially, this holds for $0$, so let's turn our focus to the invertible elements.

The multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ has order $q-1$.  By Lagrange's theorem, the order of every element of $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ must divide $q-1$.  In other words, for a given $x \in \mathbb{F}_q^\times$, we have $m|x| = q-1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.  Therefore, $x^{q-1} = x^{m|x|} = (x^{|x|})^m = 1^m = 1$.

Can you take it from here?

---

**Relevance**:

This exercise shows that every finite extension of a finite field is a [**normal extension**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension).  It is also true that such extensions are [**separable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension), from which we can conclude that all such extensions are [**Galois extensions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension), which are of great importance in Galois theory.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. I'm a bit confused by these steps: $(x^{|x|})^m = 1^m = 1$. Are you able to offer any further clarification? Thanks.

Comment: When an element $x$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is raised to the power of $|x|$, where $|x|$ denotes the order of the element, what do you get?

Comment: @user243742 He's basically showing that for every nonzero $s \in \Bbb F_{q}$, since the order of $s$ divides $q - 1$, then $s$ raised to $q-1$ gives the identity.  This means for every $s$, $s^{q - 1} = 1$, i.e., $s$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{q - 1} - 1$.  But since the degree of this polynomial is $q - 1$, it can have at most $q - 1$ roots.  And since $\Bbb F_{q} - \{0 \}$ has $q - 1$ elements, and each element is a root of the polynomial, then $x^{q - 1} - 1$ has exactly $q - 1$ roots, which are all of the non-zero elements of $\Bbb F_{q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x$ is a non-zero element of $F_q$, then $x^{q-1}=1$.